# Why are very long instances of certain type classes included in the prelude?

Tags: haskell

In the haskell prelude there are instances for very big tuples. For example:

```
(Ord a, Ord b, Ord c, Ord d, Ord e, Ord f, Ord g, Ord h, Ord i, Ord j, Ord k) => Ord (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k)
(Eq a, Eq b, Eq c, Eq d, Eq e, Eq f, Eq g, Eq h, Eq i, Eq j, Eq k) => Eq (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k)
```

Bounded, Read and Show also derive similar instances.
Can anyone explain to me why these instances are included in the prelude? Are datatypes that use them commonly used and if so, what for? And couldn't you just easily derive your own instance for such a datatype?

Comment: Ideally, GHC would conjure up such instances and tuple types on a need basis. I think some other SO answer had mentioned that there is no fundamental obstacle to that: only some engineering work in GHC. Since not many people need very large tuples, the stopgap solution is to include some fixed number of tuples and some fixed number of instances for these.

Comment: Think of it as a suggestion: if you have tuples that *aren't* covered by the pre-defined instances, you might want to reconsider your design.

Comment: The .NET library also has such `Tuple<>`s (up to 10 elements if I'm correct). These are not very common, but easy to use as "generic" types in case these are simply intermediate results.

Comment: I've often wondered if it weren't smart if Haskell had no tuple-types with more than two elements at all, and instead just defined `(a,...,x)` as syntactic sugar for `((a,...),x)`. Then all we'd need would be `instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (a,b)`. Tuples with more than two elements are seldom used anyway, more than four are highly frowned upon.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'd like the inductive nature of what you propose, but the extra pointer indirections under the hood sound a bit unpalatable. Unless GHC had some guarantees about being able to get rid of some of those...

Comment: @Alec for performance-critical stuff, you surely wouldn't want to use boxed tuples anyway...

Comment: @leftaroundabout Being performance-critical isn't something that is binary. I think 3+ tuples have (and should have!) some widespread use. Because they are used so widely, I think they should be optimized as much as their abstract interface allows.

Comment: @leftaroundabout IIRC, Isabelle/HOL (and maybe Agda?) uses that encoding for larger tuples. In a non-terminating language, the additional bottoms could be undesired, though. Also note that in Haskell we have `HList` which is almost the same thing -- except it is not used very much.

Comment: @leftaroundabout A talk about inductive tuples from ICFP 2016 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BqEt9d-amM